# My code doesn't open all four channels in relay module

Tags: arduino

I am making a Home automation. I have used arduino-uno, HC-05 bluetooth module and four channel relay module. I am currently stuck when I enter 'z' from my mobile my all channels of relay won't act as open switch.

I don't know why all the switches can't be opened simultaneously. Is it a problem of arduino or relay or the code ?

```cpp
String inputs;
#define relay1 2 //Connect relay1 to pin 2
#define relay2 3 //Connect relay2 to pin 3
#define relay3 4 //Connect relay3 to pin 4
#define relay4 5 //Connect relay4 to pin 5
int val1=0;
int val2=0;
int val3=0;
int val4=0;
int val5=0;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); //Set rate for communicating with phone
    pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT); //Set relay1 as an output
    pinMode(relay2, OUTPUT); //Set relay2 as an output
    pinMode(relay3, OUTPUT); //Set relay1 as an output
    pinMode(relay4, OUTPUT); //Set relay2 as an output
    digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH); //Switch relay1 off
    digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH); //Swtich relay2 off
    digitalWrite(relay3, HIGH); //Switch relay3 off
    digitalWrite(relay4, HIGH); //Swtich relay4 off
}

void loop()
{
    while(Serial.available()) //Check if there are available bytes to read
    {
        delay(10); //Delay to make it stable
        char c = Serial.read(); //Conduct a serial read
        if (c == '#'){
            break; //Stop the loop once # is detected after a word
        }
        inputs += c; //Means inputs = inputs + c
    }

    if (inputs.length() >0)
    {
        Serial.println(inputs);

        if(inputs == "a") 
        {
            if(val1==0)
            {
                digitalWrite(relay1,LOW);
                val1=1;
            }
            else
            {
                digitalWrite(relay1,HIGH);
                val1=0;
            }  
                delay(100);
        }
        else if(inputs == "b") 
        {
            if(val2==0)
            {
                digitalWrite(relay2,LOW);
                val2=1;
            }
            else
            {
                digitalWrite(relay2,HIGH);
                val2=0;
            }  
            delay(100);
        }
        else if(inputs == "c") 
        {
            if(val3==0)
            {
                digitalWrite(relay3,LOW);
                val3=1;
            }
            else
            {
                digitalWrite(relay3,HIGH);
                val3=0;
            }  
            delay(100);
        }
        else if(inputs == "d") 
        {
            if(val4==0)
            {
                digitalWrite(relay4,LOW);
                val4=1;
            }
            else
            {
                digitalWrite(relay4,HIGH);
                val4=0;
            }  
            delay(100);
        }
        else if(inputs == "z") 
        {
            if(val5==0)
            {
                digitalWrite(relay1,LOW);
                digitalWrite(relay2,LOW);
                digitalWrite(relay3,LOW);
                digitalWrite(relay4,LOW);
                val5=1;
            }
            else
            {
                digitalWrite(relay1,HIGH);
                digitalWrite(relay2,HIGH);
                digitalWrite(relay3,HIGH);
                digitalWrite(relay4,HIGH);
                val5=0;
            }  
            delay(100);
        }

        inputs="";
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not comfortable with your code as you are trying to read a single char but using a string to compare it. Anyway, What are you trying to achieve and what do you get when sending `z` in monitor? Put a `print` inside the last if statement and check if it reaches to that line.

Answer (score 0):

Many times relays use much current. And arduino has limited current capacity maybe these is the reason why they can't be opened simultaneously.